# How to prevent recursion in entity in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have a simple web app which render entity in json format. Here is my tables and controller:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

My `Employee` table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;
```

And controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return employeeRepository.get(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/student",
                     method = RequestMethod.POST,
                     consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void saveStudent (@ModelAttribute Employee student){
        employeeRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

Here is my question. When I'm trying to get data from `http://localhost:8080/employee/4` I'm getting recursively json like this

```
{"id":4,"name":"Tim","company":{"id":2,"name":"SoftServe","employees":[
        {"id":2,"name":"Tim","company":{"id":2,"name":"SoftServe","employees":[
            {"id":2,"name":"Tim","company":{"id":2,"name":"SoftServe","employees":
....and so on
```

Is there any solution for return not recursive entity?

Comment: Look into the Jackson annotations for back references or id references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Jackson:

You can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation to completely exclude the serialization of that property.. but I think that it is not what you want.

Another option is to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.

This will resolve your circular reference.